# Outlook like Scheduling component for a GWT based web application

Tags: java, jquery, gwt, scheduling

My requirement is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882803/looking-for-a-scheduling-calendar-component) post, but the solution there is a Delhi / C++ component which I don't think I can use in my Java + GWT based application. Basically, in my UI I want to display a list of people on the Y-axis and on the X-axis their schedules with a look and feel same as Outlook Meeting Scheduler. There is slight caveat though, the schedules need to show intersection (matches) of times with one particular user i.e. if users X, Y & Zs schedule are to be shown on the UI, then instead of showing their individual calendars, the component needs to show those time at which they can meet another person A. So, the X-axis basically show a white box for times where both X & A can meet for X's schedule, white box where Y & A can meet for Y's schedule etc. Rest all the slots will be blocked because user A can not meet on those times.

Are there any Java / Jquery based components that support such kind of UI? I know we might have to tweak a few things to do the intersection part, but having a component similar to Outlook is a good start.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at gwt-cal. It is excatly what you are looking for. They even have an Outlook theme, as well as iCal and Google Calendar:
http://code.google.com/p/gwt-cal/

Comment: Thanks Adrian. This looks good, but from a quick-glance it looks suitable for a single person's calendar, and I am not sure if it will be possible for it to be extended/modified to show multiple people's calendar...let alone the intersection (as I mentioned in my question). But I'll definitely take a deeper look. Thanks.